# Programming a UITableView Controller's UINavigationItem

Tags: ipad

I have a UITableView Controller that is embedded in a UINavigation Controller. I need to programmatically toggle its right UINavigationItem between a UITextField and a UIBarButtonItem. I need the UITextField to collect a password. I know how to set the right UINavigationItem to the UIBarButtonItem, but how can I set the right UINavigationItem to be the UITextField?

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:textField]autorelease];
```

it may helps you.....

Comment: I have another more serious problem ... getting a sigabrt at performSegue ... Can I send you my project to look at. I'm stuck ... on this for many many hours? Also no detailed error messages in the console ... why?